# Do I create an ER Diagram before or after normalization?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, entity-relationship, diagram, database-normalization

I'm learning about creating databases in MySQL and one of the theoretical parts is developing ER diagram.
Do I really need it when making my own project? And if I want to create one, do I create it after normalization of relations?

Comment: An ER diagram & DDL describe a design. To *come up with a design* you should follow some *information modeling method*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). You're not *required* to do it. But it can definitely help to keep a clear overview over your scheme.

2). I'd just start by making an ER diagram and updating it after, or during,  normalization. You could use tools like [MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to easily make and manage ER diagrams

Answer (score -1):

Normalization technique must be the part of database refinement which has to be carried out before Entity Relationship Diagram.
As in ERD technique, we find out Primary Key and Foreign Key, using the same relationship amongst the entities.